# Differential Service on 2015 F150 at 100,000 miles

Tags: ford, f-150, scheduled-maintenance, differential

What is the importance of 100,000 mile front and rear differential service on my 2015 F150 4WD King Ranch

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Mileage you should change the gear lube depends on the severity of the duty it has performed, ie. heavy towing all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The service schedule is defined by the engineers so that the oil does what it is meant to.

If you don’t change it and do another 100k then there may be damage or a failure.

But if you do change it, then it is part of preventive maintenance which reduces the liklihood of problems - never gets to zero though.

So, it’s down to you - do you look after it or not. Your choice.